# Is it faster to use strlen() than just check for null character in a for loop?

Tags: c, strlen

I've only been able to find two posts related to this topic. In one post, the code in question was written such that strlen() was called in every iteration of the loop, which many users pointed out would cause the loop to be much slower but didn't discuss the case in which you store the result of strlen() in a variable and then use it in the condition of the loop. In the other post, ([Why is strlen() about 20 times faster than manually looping to check for null-terminated character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370060/why-is-strlen-about-20-times-faster-than-manually-looping-to-check-for-null-te)) a user pointed out that the strlen() function has been optimized over time, making it faster, but I'm still a bit confused as to how exactly storing strlen() in a variable and using it in a loop condition could make it so much faster and was hoping someone with more knowledge on how strlen() is optimized could explain it to me.

Edit: From @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. 's comment, I see now that the other post is referring to using strlen() rather manually looping through the string to find its length. But, I would still like to know if there is a difference in speed between using strlen() in the loop condition or just checking for the null character.

*Side Note:* I raise the question because I was working on a rather straightforward problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/ransom-note/) in which you are tasked with writing a function that takes two strings, `ransomNote` and `magazine`, and determines whether or not the `ransomNote` can be constructed using only the characters from the `magazine` (each character in  `magazine` may only be used once), and came up with two possible solutions:

```
bool canConstruct(char * ransomNote, char * magazine){
    int magCharCount[26] = {0};
    for (int i = 0, magLen = strlen(magazine); i < magLen; ++i) ++magCharCount[magazine[i] - 'a']; 
    for (int i = 0, rNotelen = strlen(ransomNote); i < rNotelen; ++i) if (--magCharCount[ransomNote[i] - 'a'] < 0) return false; 
    return true;
}

bool canConstruct(char * ransomNote, char * magazine){
    int magCharCount[26] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; *magazine; ++magazine) ++magCharCount[*magazine - 'a'];
    for (int i = 0; *ransomNote; ++ransomNote) if (--magCharCount[*ransomNote - 'a'] < 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

In most of my CS classes, it seems my professors have favored the second implementation and other solutions to the problem do as well.

Comment: You are mixing two unrelated subjects (1) strlen vs manually written loop and (2) extracting repeated computation out of a loop.

Comment: On which compiler? Both comparisons (`i < magLen`) and dereferencing (`*magazine`) are constant-time operations, though individual implementations differ.

Comment: @RyanZhang currently using clang 11.

Comment: The functions makes a program using them have undefined behavior. Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and test your functions.

Comment: @JB032133 Consider if `strlen(magazine) == INT_MAX + 1`.  `for (int i = 0; *magazine; ++magazine)` iterates `INT_MAX + 1` times.  How many times does `for (int i = 0, magLen = strlen(magazine); i < magLen; ++i)` iterate?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This would depend on the compiler, right? But regardless, definitely not the right number of iterations since I'm storing the result in an int.

Comment: The conversion of the result of `strlen()` to an `int`, that is out of range of an `int` is implementation defined behavior.  Commonly would result in `magLen == INT_MIN` here and so no iterations. IMO, concerns about efficiency tend to overlook functionality impact and negate any micro-optimization.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  I would have this issue with the range regardless of what type I use, right? And for that reason it would probably be better to use the second implementation?

Comment: @JB032133 The second has no index range issue.  The first should use `size_t` as _string_ lengths are always in the range `[0...SIZE_MAX)`.  Using `size_t` instead of `int` may slow performance.  Which is more important. speed or correct functionality over all possible legitimate inputs?  Both have `int magCharCount[26]` issues as `int magCharCount[i]` may overflow unless `size_t magCharCount[26]` is used.  But then `--magCharCount[ransomNote[i] - 'a'] < 0` is never true due to `size_t` being _unsigned_.  That is better as `magCharCount[ransomNote[i] - 'a']--  == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for pointing this out; I did not consider those edge cases.

Comment: IMO, good  competitive programming would stress the edge and corner cases too, but instead they are more about micro-optimizations than good practice.  Again - correct functionality first (for all legit inputs), then worry about speed.  Also [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you're using `strlen()` or not, you need to loop through the strings anyway.

Therefore the solution using `strlen()` simply adds a second going through the loop.  It might be fast, but it's not needed.

In the second solution, without `strlen()`, `*magazine` and `*ransomNote` are accessed twice each; for checking `\0` and for the actual work.  A compiler can optimise this to one access (which you needed anyway).

To conclude: Using `strlen()` seems less elegant because it's not needed, and will probably be slower.

EDIT: Some more background: `strlen()` is typically optimised for each platform using machine language.  CPUs can have special instructions that make tasks like this very fast.  You can never beat this hand-optimised machine code with a regular loop in C (unless a compiler could/would understand what you're doing and replace it with optimised code).

Also a compiler, that of course 'knows' `strlen()` and similar library functions, could replace it with a chunk of instructions and don't even do a proper function call.  (This is one type of optimisation that could also be done for small(er) user functions.)

General advice: Always write complete `for`/`if`/... blocks with `{` and `}` because the one-liners you have at the moment are confusing to the eye.  The less visual forms of the same source code structure, the easier it becomes to process for us people.

```
bool canConstruct(char * ransomNote, char * magazine)
{
    int magCharCount[26] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; *magazine; ++magazine)
    {
        ++magCharCount[*magazine - 'a'];
    }

    for (int i = 0; *ransomNote; ++ransomNote)
    {
        return (--magCharCount[*ransomNote - 'a'] < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the speed would mainly depend on the compiler you're using? (Also, thanks for the tip. I generally see people writing one line for loops on leetcode and assumed it was the norm, but I guess it's just for show, and I don't know too much about proper coding style yet.)

Comment: Is that 'return' in the second loop meant to be 'if'? I don't want to edit your code. :-)

Comment: Using the proper higher-level method/architecture/algorithm is the best way to get performant code.  It's often not necessary to look at smaller details we're doing here, although it's good practice to be aware and choose what seems faster while not loosing on clarity.  It's nice/good to read about the large variety of compiler optimisations and keep these in the back of your head.  About style: I think that too many developers are not aware of humane/ergonomic aspect/effects of code styles and therefore say it's 'just a matter of taste'.  Enjoy C!

Comment: @JB032133 Added more background.

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping OP does not take away the best thing to do with the sample code posted above as to always code one way or another.

A slightly changed case results in 2 different functionalities, depending on pre-computation of string length or not.

---

Consider code like the below with `s` pointing to an `n`-length string.

```
void foo1(char *s, char *p) {
  int magLen = strlen(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < magLen; ++i) {
    *p++ = 0;
  }
}

void foo2(char *s, char *p) {
  for (int i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
    *p++ = 0;
  }
}

void foo3(char * restrict s, char * restrict p) {
  for (int i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
    *p++ = 0;
  }
}
```

`foo1()` and `foo3()` iterates `n` times.

`foo2()` may iterate **up to** `n` times.  In `foo1()` and `foo2()`, the compiler cannot assume the *string* pointed to by `s`, and the string pointed to by `p` do not overlap.  With `foo1()`, it makes no difference.  With `foo2()`, the loop may stop early due to a new *null character* appearing in the `s` string.

**Moral of the story**: code for correct functionality and avoid [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482508/is-it-faster-to-use-strlen-than-just-check-for-null-character-in-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment129765998_73482508) before worrying about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning first of all: back in the old days, there was a performance difference between

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
```

and

```
size_t length = strlen(str);
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
```

Very old compilers failed to optimize the `strlen()` call so that it was only done once, even though `str` wasn't changed in the loop body. So in the former version, it would actually keep calling strlen() over and over, each time starting the count from scratch, which was ridiculously slow.

This is no longer the case with optimizing compilers since some ~20 years back but the above problem occasionally pops up in performance discussions still.

---

A naive implementation of the  `strlen` function itself could look like this:

```
size_t strlen (const char* str)
{
  const char* original = str;

  while(*str != '\0')
    str++;

  return (size_t)(str - original);
}
```

As you can see, it does more than just checking for the null terminator. At a minimum it also has to store down the original address and then calculate the length at the end by subtracting the original from the pointer now pointing at the null terminator.

Another option would be a similar, also naive implementation:

```
size_t strlen (const char* str)
{
  size_t i;
  for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    ;
  return i;
}
```

This version doesn't have to perform a subtraction but it contains an additional counter variable. It may perhaps have more overhead code between the lines as it has to calculate the address manually.

It isn't obvious which of these two versions that's the more efficient; in fact when I disassemble them with an x86 compiler they boil down to a very similar amount of instructions.

If we are to compare code such as this with an application for loop like your examples, it will perform worse. Because in your algorithm you already need to do the counter/increment part, so you have effectively merged the `strlen` functionality with the application code. That's actually very hard to beat performance-wise even for a highly optimized version.

---

Now if we were to look at modern standard C library implementations, they look completely different from my naive examples. It will look something like [this example from glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strlen.c). A simplified explanation of what that code does, is to take advantage of having a 32 or 64 bit CPU, which can munch large chunks of data in a single instruction.

My naive implementations above, as well as the hand-rolled check vs `'\0'` in a loop do so one byte at a time. Whereas library implementations try do it 8 bytes at a time, utilizing the 64 bit CPU instructions. In order to do that they first need to establish the first aligned address in the string, comparing byte by byte until they find that. Then from there on compare 8 bytes at a time, searching for the null terminator.

---

As for which is the more efficient in any given scenario: it depends. If we were to compile for an 8 bit microcontroller, with no 64 bit instructions and no alignment, my naive implementations are not so naive any longer and will easily outperform the glibc version which was written for bigger CPUs. Whereas versions like the glibc one will perform great on very long strings on a 64 bit system like x86.

One can also not assume that `strlen` calls will always be inlined. In fact when I played around with one of the naive implementations in the disassembler, it inserted a call to the library version of `strlen()` in the middle of it. Any function call will always have overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that gcc would make strlen quicker than reading for a `'\0'` is because the result of `strlen()` is const and doesn't get called once every loop, compared to having to access the current memory and do a check every single loop.

Edit:

It also probably helps that

```
magLen = strlen(magazine); i < magLen;
```

Gets inlined to

```
i < strlen(magazine);
```

Checking [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org), with no optimization options you can see that `strlen(magazine)` is set to a const and is not used in any of the sub-routines

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-144] ; canConstruct1, line 13
mov rdi, rax
call strlen
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
```

[image: Godbolt.org]

Answer (score 0):

Taking this a bit sideways... The 'efficient' way may depend on the ratio of the length of the "ransom note" (and its use of unusual characters) to the length of the "magazine".

Here's something that just dives right in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
//  char *mag = "now is the time when the flowers and comforts start to fade.";
    char *mag = "now is the time when the flowers start to fade.";
    char *rsm = "send cash";
    char *cp;

    int magLen = strlen( mag );
    for( ; *rsm; rsm++ ) {
        if( !isalpha( *rsm ) ) continue;
        if( ( cp = strchr( mag, *rsm ) ) == NULL ) {
            printf( "No '%c' available now\n", *rsm );
            break;
        }
        *cp = mag[ --magLen ];
        mag[ magLen ] = '\0';
    }

    printf( "%s\n", *rsm ? "Nope" : "Yep" );


    return 0;
}
```

There's no point in searching for SP when it occurs in the ransom note.

This could be improved to only 'shift from the end' alphabetic characters.